# How to scroll smoothly in Emacs?

Tags: scroll, emacs

Am new to Emacs and am unaware of it's Lisp too and using it's nox version.
When cursor is in the last line of the current display and I hit the down arrow  <kbd>↓</kbd> , all of sudden so much of text is loaded from next page and the cursor will be in the middle of screen.

Is there a way to scroll by one (or some constant) line in these situations?

Will the technique work without any other extensions? I mean is there any built-in option to do this?

Comment: When the text string is very long, emacs struggles to jump from one line to the next, that's what I have experienced in the past.

Comment: @amalloy, Yes exactly it worked. I dint see this question in suggestions
Thanks for that

Comment: @Mojo, for long lines you can use (visual-line-mode).